# How do I know if I have Java installed on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, java

I am trying to install the FreeMind app (i know x2) on Ubuntu 9.10 but unsure I have Java. So, how can I verify that it is on my system?

Comment: => http://superuser.com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just type in "java -version" in a terminal window and it'll tell you what version, if any, you've got installed.

Comment: If this succeeds but the program still doesn't work, make sure you are using the needed Java using update-java-alternatives. The package sun-java6-jre will work for most everything.

Comment: Entered and received the following.

java version "1.6.0_0"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.6.1) (6b16-1.6.1-3ubuntu3)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode, sharing)

Sweet! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
# java -version
```

Comment: how did the 7 votes difference occur with 2 identical answers? :)

Comment: Prob since he answered first. But I still appreciate it. Thanks Bozho!

Answer (score 0):

You just type on terminal

```
$ java -version
```

and if it gives something along the following, Java is installed.

```
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.3) (7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```